# radiobuttons html jquery

Tags: jquery, html, tags, radio-button

I have the following little quiz that I made. 
http://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/z7LDr/

I would like to know how to make the radio buttons not have an option selected when they are displayed? They currently show whatever was previoulsy selected.
I would also like to know how to make some of the text i pass from within the `<script>` tag bold or how to enter a new line(I have tried `<br>` and "\n")?

Also any other general advise would be appreciated as I want to improve this little quiz using new methods( E.G advise from elsewhere ...a better way would be to use async calls with JSON data results..) tks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <Title> Title: My Quiz </title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
    <span id="question">Welcom to my Game hit next to play...</span>
    </br>
    <span id="answer" >possible answers will go here...</span>
    <div id="radio" style="display:none">
        <div id="rd1"></div><input type="radio" name="ans" value=""/>
        <div id="rd2"></div><input type="radio" name="ans" value=""/>
        <div id="rd3"></div><input type="radio" name="ans" value=""/>
        <div id="rd4"></div><input type="radio" name="ans" value=""/>
    </div>
    </br>
    <button id ="up"> next </button> 
    </br>
    </br>

    <span id="test" >--------------This is for Test Purposes------------- </span> <br>

    <span id="Qindex" >want to keep an eye on Qindex here </span> <br>

    <span id="whatRadioButton" >want to keep an eye on what radio button was selected... </span> <br>

    <span id="whatRightAnswer" >what is the right answer between [0,1,2,3]... </span>

    <!-- <button id ="next_answer"> next answer </button>   -->
    </div>

    <script>
    var allQuestions = [
    ["Who is Prime Minister of the United Kingdom?", 
    "What is my favourite colour?",
    "What shape is the moon?",
    "What year was the car invented?",
    "What day do catholics go to mass?"],[
    ["David Cameron", "Gordon Brown", "Winston Churchill", "Tony Blair"], 
    ["Red","Blue","Green","Another"],
    ["Square","Rectangle","Pentagon","Round"],
    ["1914","1924","1934","None of the above"],
    ["Never","Sunday","Tuesday","Monday"]], 
    [0,1,3,3,1]]; 
    //Correct answers go here  between 0,1,2,3
    var questionIndex = 0
    var score = 0;

            $("#up").on("click", function () {
            questionIndex+=1
            if (questionIndex <=5) {
                    $("#question").text("<b>Question " + questionIndex +"</b>: " + allQuestions[0][questionIndex-1]) 

                            document.getElementById("answer").style.display = "none"; //hide the span <span id="answer" >
                            document.getElementById("radio").style.display = "inline-block"; // display the radio buttons

                            document.getElementById("rd1").value = allQuestions[1][questionIndex-1][0]; //change the value attribute of id=rd*
                            document.getElementById("rd2").value = allQuestions[1][questionIndex-1][1];
                            document.getElementById("rd3").value = allQuestions[1][questionIndex-1][2];
                            document.getElementById("rd4").value = allQuestions[1][questionIndex-1][3];
                            document.getElementById("rd1").innerHTML = allQuestions[1][questionIndex-1][0]; //change the innerHTML(the text that    
                            document.getElementById("rd2").innerHTML = allQuestions[1][questionIndex-1][1]; //appear in the browser) of id=rd*
                            document.getElementById("rd3").innerHTML = allQuestions[1][questionIndex-1][2];
                            document.getElementById("rd4").innerHTML = allQuestions[1][questionIndex-1][3];
                            //document.getElementById("rd1").checked==false; // trying to reset no radio button is selected - does not work
                            //document.getElementById("rd2").checked==false;
                            //document.getElementById("rd3").checked==false;
                            //document.getElementById("rd4").checked==false;

                    var radioButtons = $("#radio input:radio[name='ans']");
                    var selectedIndex = radioButtons.index(radioButtons.filter(':checked'));

                    if(selectedIndex ===allQuestions[2][questionIndex-2]) {
                        score+=1;
                    }

                    //these are for test purposes
                    $("#whatRadioButton").text("What index answer you selected[0,1,2,3] = " + selectedIndex)
                    $("#Qindex").text("QuestionIndex = " + questionIndex) 
                    $("#whatRightAnswer").text( "Correct answer index is: " + allQuestions[2][questionIndex-2] + "\n" + 
                                                "Answer selected was: " +  selectedIndex + 
                                                "Your score is: " + score )
            }
            else if(questionIndex ===6){//end of game //no more questions

                    document.getElementById("radio").style.display = "none";//hide these id's for the end of the game 
                    document.getElementById("up").style.display = "none"; //hide the next button with id = up
                    $("#Qindex").text("QuestionIndex = " + questionIndex) 

                    var radioButtons = $("#radio input:radio[name='ans']");
                    var selectedIndex = radioButtons.index(radioButtons.filter(':checked'));

                    if(selectedIndex ===allQuestions[2][questionIndex-2]) {
                        score+=1;
                    }

                    $("#question").text("This is the End of the Quiz <br> Your score was " + score + "/5 \n Thanks you for playing...") 

                    //these is for test purposes...
                    $("#whatRadioButton").text("What index answer you selected[0,1,2,3] = " + selectedIndex)
                    $("#whatRightAnswer").text( "Correct answer index is: " + allQuestions[2][questionIndex-2] + "\n" + 
                                                "Answer selected was: " +  selectedIndex + 
                                                "Your score is: " + score )

            }

            });


    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Dont you have any db to store quiz questions?? ..the radio buttons should be dynamic like questions . now its having static id .

Comment: hi zod, think that's what I'm working towards, just not sure how its done at this stage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To uncheck radio you can add

```
$('[name="ans"]').prop('checked', false);
```

to

```
$("#up").on("click", function () {
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though your radio should be dynamic, you can add this line at the end of the `click` function :

```
$(':checked').prop('checked', false)
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/z7LDr/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a library you could use plain javascript.
JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/czFRP/

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('radioButtons');
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; ++i) {
    var item = buttons[i];  
    item.checked = false;
}
```

you would also need to add a class to your radio buttons

```
<div id="rd1"></div><input type="radio" name="ans" value="" class="radioButtons"/>
<div id="rd2"></div><input type="radio" name="ans" value="" class="radioButtons"/>
<div id="rd3"></div><input type="radio" name="ans" value="" class="radioButtons"/>
<div id="rd4"></div><input type="radio" name="ans" value="" class="radioButtons"/>
```